Flutter Firebase Instance authStateChanges() only updates screen after hot restart
I have an auth check screen setup with a builder listening to authStateChanges() and to hopefully update the screen and show the home page when the user logs in. I've tried messing with the auth check, which is my main suspicion, and also with the login and log out functions. I do not know what else to do, any help is appreciated.
@override //this is a stateful widget btw
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: AuthHelper().authStateChanges, // just a getter for FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? const HomeScreenLayout()
            : const LoginOptionsScreen();
      },
    );
  }

And this is what the button looks like:
StandardButton(
    ...,
    onTap: () {
        AuthHelper().signInWithEmail(
            email: userEmail.text.trim(),
            password: password.text.trim(),
        );
    },
),
// the method inside AuthHelper class
Future<void> signInWithEmail({email, password}) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
  }

The problem is that after inputting the correct login info, and pressing the button, the screen that should otherwise update, does not. I have to hot restart the app every time to see the changes.
The weird part is that the sign out function for the same class, working with the exact same button in the home screen, does work properly and redirects me to the login page automatically
StandardButton(
    ...,
    onTap: () {
        AuthHelper().signOut();
    },
),
// the method inside AuthHelper class
Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _firebaseInstance.signOut();
  }


It works for me here: https://zapp.run/edit/auth-example-z124069j1250
When you sign-in with email/password, the auth state listener picks up the changes.

Yeah I feared it would work on other people's machines, because I have the exact same setup in another project of mine, from which I have copied most of that code from, and it works perfectly there.  This seems to occur only in this project, with that codebase

In that case it seems the code isn't the problem and it's around something in the project configuration. I'd recommend checking whether email enumeration protection is enabled on one and not the other, although I get the same API response either way.
